# Contar las palabras repetidas en un diccionario en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, diccionarios

Quisiera contar todas las palabras repetidas de este diccionario y agruparlos en otro diccionario.

```
data = [{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'España', 'type': 'LOC'}, {'text': 'Real Madrid TV', 'type': 'MISC'}, {'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, {'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'Atlético de Madrid', 'type': 'LOC'}, {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'Real Mad', 'type': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'Ricardo Rodríguez', 'type': 'PER'}]
```

Captura de la estructura del diccionario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el diccionario como se puede ver, la palabra **Real Madrid** se repite 4 veces, **España** se repite 2 veces, otros una vez.

Lo que quiero es crear otro diccionario adicionando la columna **Cantidad** y poner ahí los valores repetidos; osea mi nuevo diccionario quedaría con los nuevos campos: text, type y cantidad; la nueva dimensión del diccionario creo seria 6.

Esto es mi avance :

```
valor = data[0]['text']
del data[0]
count = 0
value_count = []
for x in data:
    if x['text'] == valor:
        value_count.append({'text': x['text'], 'type':x['type']})
        valor = x['text']
print (value_count)
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola Alejandro, ¿Te has planteado usar [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero te sirva este código. Puedes quitar el `if element count > 1:` en el caso de querer contar todo, repeticiones y no repeticiones.

```
data = [
{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
{'text': 'España', 'type': 'LOC'}, 
{'text': 'Real Madrid TV', 'type': 'MISC'}, 
{'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, 
{'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, 
{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
{'text': 'Atlético de Madrid', 'type': 'LOC'}, 
{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
{'text': 'Real Mad', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
{'text': 'Ricardo Rodríguez', 'type': 'PER'}]

new_datalist = []
items_found = []
for element in data:
    if (not element in items_found):
        # items_found acumula los dic que ya se analizaron para no repetirlos
        items_found.append(element)
        elem_count = data.count(element) # Se cuentan los elementos
        if elem_count > 1:
            # Si hay mas de 1 repeticion, crear el diccionario nuevo
            new_elem = {}
            new_elem['text'] = element['text']
            new_elem['type'] = element['type']
            new_elem['cantidad'] = elem_count 
            new_datalist.append(new_elem)
print(new_datalist)
```

Salida:

```
[{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG', 'cantidad': 4}, 
{'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER', 'cantidad': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas contar las repeticiones para ver si son mayores a 1 y luego
verificar si ya se encuentra en el nuevo diccionario

```
data = [{'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
        {'text': 'España', 'type': 'LOC'}, 
        {'text': 'Real Madrid TV', 'type': 'MISC'}, 
        {'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, 
        {'text': 'España', 'type': 'PER'}, 
        {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
        {'text': 'Atlético de Madrid', 'type': 'LOC'}, 
        {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
        {'text': 'Real Madrid', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
        {'text': 'Real Mad', 'type': 'ORG'}, 
        {'text': 'Ricardo Rodríguez', 'type': 'PER'}
]

data2 = [

]

def contarRepeticiones(palabra):
    cont = 0
    for i in data:
        if i['text']==palabra:
            cont+=1
    return cont


def seEcuentraenData2(palabra):
    for i in data2:
        if i['text']==palabra:
            return True
    return False            


for i in data:
    if contarRepeticiones(i['text'])>1 and seEcuentraenData2(i['text'])==False:
        data2.append({'text': i['text'], 'type': i['type'],'cantidad': contarRepeticiones(i['text'])})

print (data2)
```

Comment: Gracias, a todos en realidad está super bueno ambos, pero solo puedo escoger uno